# for loop in range where upper limit is taken from the user

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to fetch the for loop limit from the user. When I am passing that variable it's not iterating across it

```
for num in {1..$totalNodes}
```

But when I am giving a hardcoded value

```
for num in {1..10}
```

it runs fine. Can anyone please help.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Enter the total no of nodes : " totalNodes
read -p "Enter the no of Master nodes : " masterNodes

echo $totalNodes
echo $masterNodes

for num in {1..5}
    do
        echo "$num"

        read -p "Enter the Node $num IP : " node[$num]

    done

echo $node
```

Comment: here is my script :

#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Enter the total no of nodes : " totalNodes
read -p "Enter the no of Master nodes : " masterNodes

echo $totalNodes
echo $masterNodes

for num in {1..5}
    do
        echo "$num"

        read -p "Enter the Node $num IP : " node[$num]

    done

echo $node

Comment: This may not be an explicit duplicate, OP has got the logic right, it is just the issue with the brace expansion that is the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `brace-expansion` is it happens before everything else, so that the parameter expansion you are expecting to happen(expansion of variable `totalNodes` does not happen during that expansion. See from the `man bash` page,

> EXPANSION
>
> Expansion  is  performed  on  the command line after it has been split into words.  There are seven kinds of expansion performed: *brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion*.
>
> The order of expansions is: **brace expansion**; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and
>          pathname expansion.

So you will not get to what you are trying to achieve. Since you are in `bash` you can use the `C` style `for-loop` iteration, as

```
read -p "Enter the total no of nodes : " totalNodes
for (( i=1; i<=totalNodes; i++)); do
    printf "%d\n" "$i"
done
```

Comment: This works, Thanks a lot.